# How to do partial derivative with respect to a function

Tags: calculus

$f$ and $g$ are both a function of $k$ and $\theta$

$f(k,\theta)=k\cos(\theta)$

$g(k,\theta)=k\sin(\theta)$

how to do the following:

$\frac{\partial f }{\partial g}$
i.e.
$\frac{\partial(k\cos(\theta))}{\partial(k\sin(\theta))}$

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following.

By the invariance of form of differential,

$$\frac{df}{dg}=\frac{f’_\theta d\theta}{g’_\theta d\theta}=\frac{f’_\theta}{g’_\theta}=\frac{-k\sin\theta}{k\cos\theta}=-\tan\theta.$$